# struct dclaration in foundation framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, pointers, struct

I have some basic knowledge about objective c and how to declare and use Struct and how to use Typedef in order to call the Struct easier, however I see a lot of weird complicated Struct usage and declaration that I have no idea about. The following is one of them which is defined in "CFUUID.h" class in foundation framework

```
typedef const struct __CFUUID * CFUUIDRef;
```

can somebody please explain what is going on here, this is not the usual way to define a Struct according to what I have read so far. 
So it means this Struct wil be a constant that can not be changed later? 
Is the name of the Struct   _CFUUID? 
Why do wee need that pointer and what is that typedef doing here in relation to the pointer?

Answer (score 2):

I think that SO is no C tutorial. Anyway a short answer.

1. It is no definition of a struct. It is a definition of a type (`typedef`).
2. A type definition is something like an alias: The identifier (`CFUUIDRef`) stands for the type mentioned ahead of it. (`const struct __CFUUID *` aka a pointer to a structure with the identifier __CFUUID.).
3. A type definition has several advantages:

   - It makes code shorter and more readable.
   - It encapsulates information (like classes do). For example the "real" type can be changed without breaking existing code, which only relays on `CFUUIDRef` instead of its inner definition. (That's why you should not ask, what `struct __CFUUID` is. They do not want you to ask that. It is a secret.)
   - It makes things easier, if the type is a part of another construction. (I. e. an array.)
4. Yes, `const` makes it constant. Nobody should change a UUID.
5. Using pointers gives another level of indirection. This has many advantages. Additionally passing a pointer around (1 cpu word) is faster than copying the whole struct (2 or 4 cpu words).

Comment: No, this would be `struct __CFUUID * const CFUUIDRef`